# Connect to wifi programmatically on android Q(android10) to transfer files

Tags: java, connection, file-transfer, android-10.0, wifimanager

I'm building a file sharing app like (SHAREit, xender,...). My code is working fine on api level 28 and below. But I'm not able to make it work on android 10. I tried wifisuggestion and WifiNetworkSpecifier api but still not able to share files. (how could apps like SHARE it connect to wifi programmatically on android 10 without even using WifiNetworkSpecifier )?
Here' my code
Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.android.share">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Connection Utils

```
  public class ConnectionUtils{  ....initialization...
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
}public static ConnectionUtils getInstance(Context context) {
    return new ConnectionUtils(context);
}

public static String getCleanNetworkName(String networkName) {
    if (networkName == null)
        return "";
    return networkName.replace("\"", "");
}

public boolean canAccessLocation() {
    return hasLocationPermission(getContext()) && isLocationServiceEnabled();
}
public boolean canReadScanResults() {
    return getWifiManager().isWifiEnabled() && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 || canAccessLocation());
}

public boolean disableCurrentNetwork() {

    return isConnectedToAnyNetwork()
            && getWifiManager().disconnect()
            && getWifiManager().disableNetwork(getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId());
}

@WorkerThread
public String establishHotspotConnection(final Interrupter interrupter,
                                         final NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork hotspotNetwork,
                                         final ConnectionCallback connectionCallback) {
    final int pingTimeout = 1000; // ms
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String remoteAddress = null;
    boolean connectionToggled = false;
    boolean secondAttempt = false;
    boolean thirdAttempt = false;

    while (true) {
        int passedTime = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        if (passedTime >= 10000 && !secondAttempt) {
            secondAttempt = true;
            disableCurrentNetwork();
            connectionToggled = false;
        }

        if (passedTime >= 20000 && !thirdAttempt) {
            thirdAttempt = true;
            disableCurrentNetwork();
            connectionToggled = false;
        }

        if (!getWifiManager().isWifiEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Wifi is off. Making a request to turn it on");
            if (!getWifiManager().setWifiEnabled(true)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Wifi was off. The request has failed. Exiting.");
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (!isConnectedToNetwork(hotspotNetwork) && !connectionToggled) {
            Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Requested network toggle");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                toggleConnection(hotspotNetwork);
            }
            else{
                connect(hotspotNetwork.SSID,hotspotNetwork.password);
             }
            connectionToggled = true;

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Waiting to connect to the server");
            final DhcpInfo routeInfo = getWifiManager().getDhcpInfo();
            //Log.w(TAG, String.format("establishHotspotConnection(): DHCP: %s", routeInfo));

            if (routeInfo != null && routeInfo.gateway != 0) {
                final String testedRemoteAddress = NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.gateway);

                Log.d(TAG, String.format("establishHotspotConnection(): DhcpInfo: gateway: %s dns1: %s dns2: %s ipAddr: %s serverAddr: %s netMask: %s",
                        testedRemoteAddress,
                        NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.dns1),
                        NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.dns2),
                        NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.ipAddress),
                        NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.serverAddress),
                        NetworkUtils.convertInet4Address(routeInfo.netmask)));

                Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): There is DHCP info provided waiting to reach the address " + testedRemoteAddress);            

                if (UIConnectionUtils.isOSAbove(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
                        ? NetworkUtils.ping(testedRemoteAddress, pingTimeout)
                        : NetworkUtils.ping(testedRemoteAddress)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): AP has been reached. Returning OK state.");
                    remoteAddress = testedRemoteAddress;
                    break;
                } else
                    Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Connection check ping failed");

            } else
                Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): No DHCP provided. Looping...");
        }

        if (connectionCallback.onTimePassed(1000, passedTime) || interrupter.interrupted()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "establishHotspotConnection(): Timed out or onTimePassed returned true. Exiting...");
            break;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }

    return remoteAddress;
}

public boolean hasLocationPermission(Context context) {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public ConnectivityManager getConnectivityManager() {
    return mConnectivityManager;
}

public HotspotUtils getHotspotUtils() {
    return mHotspotUtils;
}

public LocationManager getLocationManager() {
    return mLocationManager;
}

public WifiManager getWifiManager() {
    return mWifiManager;
}

public boolean isConnectionSelfNetwork() {
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo();

    return wifiInfo != null
            && getCleanNetworkName(wifiInfo.getSSID()).startsWith(AppConfig.PREFIX_ACCESS_POINT);
}

public boolean isConnectedToAnyNetwork() {
    NetworkInfo info = getConnectivityManager().getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return info != null
            && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
            && info.isConnected();
}

public boolean isConnectedToNetwork(NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork hotspotNetwork) {
    if (!isConnectedToAnyNetwork())
        return false;

    if (hotspotNetwork.BSSID != null)
        return hotspotNetwork.BSSID.equals(getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo().getBSSID());

    return hotspotNetwork.SSID.equals(getCleanNetworkName(getWifiManager().getConnectionInfo().getSSID()));
}

public boolean isLocationServiceEnabled() {
    return mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

public boolean isMobileDataActive() {
    return mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
}

public boolean toggleConnection(NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork hotspotNetwork) {
    if (!isConnectedToNetwork(hotspotNetwork)) {
        if (isConnectedToAnyNetwork())
            disableCurrentNetwork();

        WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();

        config.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", hotspotNetwork.SSID);
    ...........(configuation)

        try {
            int netId = getWifiManager().addNetwork(config);

            if (/*Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= */UIConnectionUtils.isOSAbove(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)) {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") List<WifiConfiguration> list = getWifiManager().getConfiguredNetworks();
                for (WifiConfiguration hotspotWifi : list) {
                    if (hotspotWifi.SSID != null && hotspotWifi.SSID.equalsIgnoreCase(config.SSID)) {
                        getWifiManager().disconnect();
                        getWifiManager().enableNetwork(hotspotWifi.networkId, true);
                        return getWifiManager().reconnect();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                getWifiManager().disconnect();
                getWifiManager().enableNetwork(netId, true);
                return getWifiManager().reconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            disableCurrentNetwork();
            return false;
        }
    }

    disableCurrentNetwork();
    return false;
}

public interface ConnectionCallback {
    boolean onTimePassed(int delimiter, long timePassed);
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public boolean connect(String ssid, String password){
    if (mConnectivityManager == null) {
        return false;
    }
    NetworkSpecifier networkSpecifier;
        networkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .setSsid(ssid)
                .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                .build();        
    NetworkRequest networkRequest  = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(networkSpecifier)
            .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .build();
    mConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, mNetworkCallback);
    return true;
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback mNetworkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
        super.onAvailable(network);
        //phone is connected to wifi network
        mConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);

    }
...implement members}
```

UiConnectionUtil

```
public class UIConnectionUtils{ initialize ....         public void makeAcquaintance(final Activity activity, final UITask task, final Object object, final int accessPin,
                             final NetworkDeviceLoader.OnDeviceRegisteredListener registerListener)
{
    WorkerService.RunningTask runningTask = new WorkerService.RunningTask()
    {
        private boolean mConnected = false;
        private String mRemoteAddress;

        @Override
        public void onRun()
        {
            final DialogInterface.OnClickListener retryButtonListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    makeAcquaintance(activity, task, object, accessPin, registerListener);
                }
            };

            try {
                if (object instanceof NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork) {
                    mRemoteAddress = getConnectionUtils().establishHotspotConnection(getInterrupter(),
                            (NetworkDeviceListAdapter.HotspotNetwork) object,
                            new ConnectionUtils.ConnectionCallback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTimePassed(int delimiter, long timePassed)
                                {
                                    return timePassed >= 30000;
                                }
                            });
                } else if (object instanceof String)
                    mRemoteAddress = (String) object;

                if (mRemoteAddress != null) {
                    mConnected = setupConnection(activity, mRemoteAddress, accessPin, new NetworkDeviceLoader.OnDeviceRegisteredListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDeviceRegistered(final AccessDatabase database, final NetworkDevice device, final NetworkDevice.Connection connection)
                        {
                            // we may be working with direct IP scan
                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    if (registerListener != null)
                                        registerListener.onDeviceRegistered(database, device, connection);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, retryButtonListener) != null;
                }

                if (!mConnected && !getInterrupter().interruptedByUser())
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            if (!activity.isFinishing()) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                                        .setMessage(R.string.mesg_connectionFailure)
                                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.butn_close, null)
                                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.butn_retry, retryButtonListener);

                                if (object instanceof NetworkDevice)
                                    dialogBuilder.setTitle(((NetworkDevice) object).nickname);

                                dialogBuilder.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if (task != null && !activity.isFinishing())
                            task.updateTaskStopped();
                    }
                });
            }
            // We can't add dialog outside of the else statement as it may close other dialogs as well
        }
    }.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.mesg_completing))
            .setIconRes(R.drawable.ic_compare_arrows_white_24dp_static);

    runningTask.run(activity);

    if (task != null)
        task.updateTaskStarted(runningTask.getInterrupter());
}

public boolean notifyWirelessRequestHandled()
{
    boolean returnedState = mWirelessEnableRequested;

    mWirelessEnableRequested = false;

    return returnedState;
}

@WorkerThread
public NetworkDevice setupConnection(final Activity activity,
                                     final String ipAddress,
                                     final int accessPin,
                                     final NetworkDeviceLoader.OnDeviceRegisteredListener listener,
                                     final DialogInterface.OnClickListener retryButtonListener)
{
    return CommunicationBridge.connect(AppUtils.getDatabase(activity), NetworkDevice.class, new CommunicationBridge.Client.ConnectionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onConnect(CommunicationBridge.Client client)
        {
            try {
                client.setSecureKey(accessPin);

                CoolSocket.ActiveConnection activeConnection = client.connectWithHandshake(ipAddress, false);
                NetworkDevice device = client.loadDevice(activeConnection);

                activeConnection.reply(new JSONObject()
                        .put(Keyword.REQUEST, Keyword.REQUEST_ACQUAINTANCE)
                        .toString());

                JSONObject receivedReply = new JSONObject(activeConnection.receive().response);

                if (receivedReply.has(Keyword.RESULT)
                        && receivedReply.getBoolean(Keyword.RESULT)
                        && device.deviceId != null) {
                    final NetworkDevice.Connection connection = NetworkDeviceLoader.processConnection(AppUtils.getDatabase(activity), device, ipAddress);

                    device.lastUsageTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    device.tmpSecureKey = accessPin;
                    device.isRestricted = false;
                    device.isTrusted = true;

                    AppUtils.getDatabase(activity).publish(device);

                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onDeviceRegistered(AppUtils.getDatabase(activity), device, connection);
                } else
                    showConnectionRejectionInformation(activity, device, receivedReply, retryButtonListener);

                client.setReturn(device);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}



public interface RequestWatcher
{
    void onResultReturned(boolean result, boolean shouldWait);
}}
```

Comment: did you find any solution of it?